# These indefinite integrals evaluate in 12.0 but not in 12.1 - what can be done?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, version-12.1

The following  two integrals evaluate OK in version 12.0 on windows 10 but when I tried them again under version 12.1 on the same PC they no longer evaluate.

Why does this happen and what to do to make them evaluate again under 12.1?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
Integrate[(a + I*a*Tan[e + f*x])^m*(c + d*Tan[e + f*x])^3, x]
Integrate[((A + B*Tan[e + f*x])*(c - I*c*Tan[e + f*x])^n)/(a + I*a*Tan[e + f*x])^2, x]
```

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: "[W]hat can be done?" Same answer as every other time: send a report to Tech Support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`TrigToExp`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TrigToExp.html) to convert the integrands to more amenable forms

```
$Version

(* "12.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 14, 2020)" *)

ClearAll["Global`*"]
```

First example

```
expr1 = (a + I*a*Tan[e + f*x])^m*(c + d*Tan[e + f*x])^3;

expr2 = Integrate[expr1 // TrigToExp // Simplify, x] // FullSimplify

(* ((((I c - d)^3 (1 + m) (2 + m) + (-I c + d) E^(
         4 I (e + f x)) (2 (c + I d)^2 + 6 c (c - I d) m + 
           3 (c - I d)^2 m^2) + (c + I d)^2 E^(
         2 I (e + f x)) (2 + m) (d (2 - 3 m) - I c (2 + 3 m)))/(m (1 + m) (2 +
           m)) - I (c - I d)^3 E^(6 I (e + f x))
       Gamma[3 + m] Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[1, 1, 
       4 + m, -E^(2 I (e + f x))]) (a + I a Tan[e + f x])^
   m)/(2 (1 + E^(2 I (e + f x)))^2 f) *)
```

Verifying,

```
test1 = D[expr2, x] == expr1 // FullSimplify

(* True *)
```

Second example

```
expr3 = ((A + B*Tan[e + f*x])*(c - I*c*Tan[e + f*x])^n)/(a + 
      I*a*Tan[e + f*x])^2;

expr4 = Integrate[expr3 // TrigToExp // Simplify, x] // FullSimplify

(* (1/(a^2 f))2^(-4 + n) (c/(
  1 + E^(2 I (e + f x))))^n (1 + E^(
   2 I (e + f x)))^2 ((I A - B) E^(-4 I (e + f x)) + (
   1/(-2 + n))(-I A (-2 + n) + B (2 + n)) Hypergeometric2F1[2, 2 - n, 3 - n, 
     1 + E^(2 I (e + f x))]) *)
```

Verifying,

```
test2 = D[expr4, x] == expr3 // FullSimplify

(* True *)
```

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. I find it very strange that one now needs to find specific preprocessing to make it work, as this is not something one normally needed to do (as in V12). But good to know there is a workaround.

Comment: @Nasser - recommend that you report your findings to Tech Support. They may be able to determine what changed and fix it in a future version.